# Unable to Cast() generic dictionary item to DictionaryEntry when enumerated via non-generic IDictionary

Tags: .net, linq, dictionary, casting, linq-to-objects

I have some code that iterates over a non-generic [`IDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx) by first calling the LINQ [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method. However I get an invalid cast exception when passing a generic dictionary implementation even though I'm specifically using it via the non-generic `IDictionary` interface.

```
IDictionary dict = new Dictionary<object, object> {{"test", "test"}};
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    Debug.Assert(item is DictionaryEntry); // works
}
dict.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToList();     // FAILS
```

Why does the Cast method above fail when the normal iteration doesn't? Is there a reliable way to transform a non-generic dictionary into an enumeration of `DictionaryEntry` without resorting to manual list building?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the `IEnumerable` implementation on `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` enumerates KeyValuePairs. Foreach on an `IDictionary` will use the `IDictionary.GetEnumerator` function which returns an IDictionaryEnumerator (internally, this tells the `IEnumerator` function on the internal Enumerator class which type to return.) Whereas the Cast function operates on IEnumerable, which will make it return a KeyValuePair.

You could write your own Cast method to work around this, if you really *must* use the non-generic interface and DictionaryEntry

```
IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry> CastDE(IDictionary dict) {
    foreach(DictionaryEntry item in dict)
        yield return item;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. Can you suggest a workaround or is there no way to work with a Dictionary<,> via the IDictionary interface in this manner?

Comment: @UwConcept The CastDE function was intended as an answer to that question.

Comment: The code in the answer above needs an explicit cast to prevent compiler errors, so either
    foreach (DictionaryEntry item in dict) {...}
or
    yield return (DictionaryEntry)item;

Comment: @Dave_J Ah, sorry about that. I had incorrectly believed that IDictionaryEnumerator had a shadowed Current property, rather than a differently-named Entry property. If it had, it would have worked.