# How to get an IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry> out of an IDictionary?

Tags: c#

I essentially want to do this:

```
if(obj is IDictionary)
{
    return "{" + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ((IDictionary)obj).Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(e => string.Format("  {0}: {1}", PrettyString(e.Key), PrettyString(e.Value)))) + "}";
}
```

But I keep getting an invalid cast. I can do

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry e in (IDictionary)obj)
```

So why can't I do this?

---

I find this quite curious. I wrote an extension to solve the problem:

```
static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry> Entries(this IDictionary dict)
    {
        foreach (var item in dict) yield return (DictionaryEntry)item;
    }
}
```

Then I can just do:

```
((IDictionary)obj).Entries().Select(...)
```

The curious part is that Resharper tells me I can replace my extension with this:

```
return dict.Cast<DictionaryEntry>();
```

But that throws an exception. Is this a bug in Resharper? Or how `Cast` works? I'd imagine `Cast` would work exactly the way my extension does.

**Edit:** Ah.. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7683336/65387) a bit more closely. Still strange.

Comment: What is `obj` from you code? Some more context would help.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Considering it's inside an `if(obj is IDictionary)` block, it's guaranteed to be an `IDictionary`. I'm testing with `Dictionary<string, string>` if it makes any difference. The actual type of `obj` is `object`.

Comment: Just a tip: You're much better off using the generic version with `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: @Porges: I don't know what `TKey` and `TValue` are; is there any benefit using `KeyValuePair<object,object>` over `DictionaryEntry`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683294

Comment: @Mark: Are you only dealing with non-generic Dictionaries in your real code? You said you were testing with `Dictionary<string,string>`, so I thought you could switch to generic versions. Nevermind then :)

Comment: I'm curious why you insist on using `IDictionary` in an obviously .NET 3.5+ app (your update includes extension methods).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to Cast() generic dictionary item to DictionaryEntry when enumerated via non-generic IDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683294/unable-to-cast-generic-dictionary-item-to-dictionaryentry-when-enumerated-via)

Comment: @DStanley: There's a "close" link for flagging dupes. I wouldn't be upset if you used that instead of writing out the comment ;)

Comment: @Mark I don't have "close" privileges (yet) :)

Comment: @M.Babcock: I'm writing a method for pretty-printing dictionaries. I want it to work on *all* dictionaries; I can't explicitly write out every variation TKey and TValue. Sometimes you just don't know the types :)

Comment: @Mark - If that is the case are you still looking for an answer? Generics could solve this problem very simply.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Nope. Not looking for an answer anymore. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Also, @Babcock and Pogres: I could overload my PrettyPrint function multiple times for each type, and that would give a much cleaner solution, but I'd still want the `IDictionary` fallback to cover all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the key and value types known at compile time?  If so, you could make a generic method for the pretty-print and let the compiler infer the types for you, like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var obj = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "foo", "bar" },
            { "baz", "ack" },
        };

    var stringVersion = GetStringVersion(obj);

    Console.WriteLine(stringVersion);
}

private static string GetStringVersion<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
{
    return "{" + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dict.Select(e => string.Format("  {0}: {1}", e.Key, e.Value))) + "}";
}
```

In terms of the behavior you're seeing, it's a known weird case due to backwards compat and a design decision:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/09/03/225473.aspx

> We discussed a problem with implementation of IEnumerable on
>   Dictionary. What type should IEnumerable.GetEnumerator().Current
>   return? KeyValuePair or DictionaryEntry? Same for
>   ICollection.CopyTo. Instances of what type should be copied to the
>   array?
>
> We decided the following:
>
> 1. `IEnumerable` and `ICollection` interface implementations will use `KeyValuePair<K,V>` as the item type.
> 2. ***`IDictionary` specific members (`GetEnumerator` returning `IDictionaryEnumerator`) will use `DictionaryEntry` as the item type.***
>
> The reason is that we are in a process of making a change where `IEnumerator<T>` would extend `IEnumerator`. It would be very strange if walking the hierarchy from `Dictionary<K,V>`->`IEnumerable<T>`->`IEnumerable` we suddenly changed the type of the item returned from enumerators.

Due to that design decision (during the creation of .NET 2.0), when you operate on the non-generic IEnumerable, the GetEnumerator() call returns IDictionaryEnumerator, and the resulting items are of type DictionaryEntry (presumably for back-compat with Hashtable-type iteration).  However, once you are calling the generic IEnumerable (which is what happens once you do Cast() or OfType(), you'll get KeyValuePair items instead.

Note that this is a particular oddity about using Dictionary in a non-generic context - Hashtable (still) iterates as DictionaryEntry items just fine, and 'normal' iteration over Dictionary gives you KeyValuePair items.

As others have said, you should stick with the generic access if you can, since it'll let you avoid this little 'gotcha' in the design decisions of Dictionary.

Comment: This is viable. I don't know why it didn't occur to me to make the whole PrettyPrint method generic. I can still use the vanilla `IDictionary` as a fallback. I'd still use `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` in the example you provide though.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast the IDictionary itself into a DictionaryEntry.  In the foreach loop you are not casting the IDictionary, but the items contained in it.

You can do this and use a list:

```
var list = new List<DictionaryEntry>();
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in (IDictionary)obj)
    list.Add(de);
return "{" + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.Select(e => string.Format("  {0}: {1}", PrettyString(e.Key), PrettyString(e.Value)))) + "}";
```

Comment: I thought that what might have been happening, but I thought `.Cast` operated on each of elements in an IEnumerable. Regardless though, how do I fix it? `.GetEnumerator().Cast<>` doesn't seem to be a thing.

Comment: See my code above.  Hope it works, sorry I haven't tested it.

Comment: `((IDictionary)obj).Select` doesn't exist. `IDictionary` implements `IEnumerable` not `IEnumerable<T>`, otherwise I wouldn't have any problems ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but...now you're just converting an `IDictionary` into an `IList`...which I guess works, but I might as well have unrolled my `Select` then.

Comment: Yeah I know, I mean you may as well just convert it into strings and do the join if your going to do what I did above...

Comment: Cast() casts each element, not the entire collection - your first sentence is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

I've voted to close this question, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683294/unable-to-cast-generic-dictionary-item-to-dictionaryentry-when-enumerated-via/7683336#7683336) is good enough.

This is my solution:

```
static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry> Entries(this IDictionary dict)
    {
        foreach (var item in dict) yield return (DictionaryEntry)item;
    }
}
```

Note that

```
 return dict.Cast<DictionaryEntry>();
```

Does *not* work here, despite what Resharper tells you.