# C# cast Dictionary<string, AnyType> to Dictionary<string, Object> (Involving Reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

Is it possible to cast a `Dictionary<string, Anything>` to a consistent intermediate generic type?  So I would be able to cast `<string, string>`, `<string, bool>`, `<string, int>`, `<string, anything>` all to the same type of dictionary?

I am working on a project that is using heavy reflection and I need to be able to process DIctionary types as such:

```
FieldInfo field = this.GetType().GetField(fieldName);
Dictionary<string, Object> dict = (Dictionary<string, Object>)field.GetValue(this);
```

The above code is what I currently have and the program always fails at the cast from field.GetValue to the generic `Dictionary<string, Object>`.

Is there a way to do this?  Or should I just figure out a different way to process these Dictionaries?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Following [AakashM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10206944/113787), the Cast doesn't seem to play ball. You can get around it by using a little helper method though:

```
IDictionary dictionary = (IDictionary)field.GetValue(this);
Dictionary<string, object> newDictionary = CastDict(dictionary)
                                           .ToDictionary(entry => (string)entry.Key,
                                                         entry => entry.Value);

private IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry> CastDict(IDictionary dictionary)
{
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in dictionary)
    {
        yield return entry;
    }
}
```

The duck typing in foreach is handy in this instance.

Comment: This worked like a charm,  Thank you both AakashM and Gibsnag.  This was giving me trouble for a while.

Comment: There's no need for a special CastDict method, you can just use the normal Cast<DictionaryEntry>() LINQ operator.

Comment: @NathanBaulch Got an exmaple of this? `Cast<T>` return an `IEnumerable<T>` which isn't dictionaryable?

Answer (score 18):

Is this helping you ?

```
Dictionary<a, b> output =
   input.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => (SomeType)item.Value);
```

Comment: I can not actually called the ToDictionary method since I am using reflection.  I might be able to use more reflection to get to the ToDictionary method, but then I would be uncertain on how to pass those kinds of parameters into it.

Answer (score 10):

Even if you could find some way to express this, it would be the wrong thing to do - it's not true that a `Dictionary<string, bool>` **is** a `Dictionary<string, object>`, so we definitely don't want to **cast**. Consider that if we *could* cast, we could try and put a `string` in as a value, which obviously doesn't fit!

What we can do, however, is cast to the non-generic `IDictionary` (which all `Dictionary<,>`s implement), then use that to construct a *new* `Dictionary<string, object>` with the same values:

```
FieldInfo field = this.GetType().GetField(fieldName);
IDictionary dictionary = (IDictionary)field.GetValue(this);
Dictionary<string, object> newDictionary = 
    dictionary
    .Cast<dynamic>()
    .ToDictionary(entry => (string)entry.Key,
                  entry => entry.Value);
```

(note that you can't use `.Cast<DictionaryEntry>` here for [the reasons discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9713698). If you're pre-C# 4, and so don't have `dynamic`, you'll have to do the enumeration manually, as [Gibsnag's answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10207397/71059))

Comment: I am still getting an error "Specified cast is not valid" with that code. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the actual type of the object that `field.GetValue()` returns?

Comment: Well I know for a fact that it is trying to get a `Dictionary<string, string>` but that is just because it is my first test case.  During runtime `Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(this).GetType().Name);` prints out "Dictionary`2".   Edit: I just ran `Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(this));` and got `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String, System.String]`

Comment: You can convert a `bool` to `object` - it is referred to as boxing, so the technique would be valid.

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation of What's Wrong: Variance

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10206944/5134722):

> it's not true that a `Dictionary<string, bool>` is a `Dictionary<string,object>`

Let me explain why. It all has to do with [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) in C#. In summary, neither the key type `K` nor the value type `V` in `Dictionary<K, V>` is either purely an input parameter or an output parameter across the entire dictionary. So neither generic type can be cast to a weaker or a stronger type.

If you cast to a weaker type, then you break inputs. For example the `Add` function which expects types `K, V` or stronger cannot accept supertypes of either of `K, V`. If you cast to a stronger type, you break outputs. For example, the indexer property returns a type `V`. How can we cast this safely to a sub-type of `V`, knowing only that the original type is `V`? We can't.

### A Type-Safe Partial Solution Using Variant Generics

There is a way to allow strongly-typed casting, but only on partial fragments of the original dictionary interface which are consistent in terms of covariance/contravariance of generic parameters. This solution uses a wrapper type which implements a bunch of partial interfaces. Each partial interface has a specific type of combination of co/contra-variance of the key/value type. Then we combine all these partial interfaces into a master interface and implement that through a backing object which is a regular dictionary. Here goes. First, the interfaces:

```
public interface IDictionaryBase
{
    int Count { get; }
    bool IsReadOnly { get; }
    void Clear();
}

public interface IInKeyInValueSemiDictionary<in K, in V> : IDictionaryBase, IInKeySemiDictionary<K>
{
    V this[K key] { set; }
    void Add(K key, V value);
}

public interface IInKeyOutValueSemiDictionary<in K, out V> : IDictionaryBase, IInKeySemiDictionary<K>, IOutValueSemiDictionary<V>
{
    V this[K key] { get; }
    ISuccessTuple<V> TryGetValue(K key);
}

public interface ISuccessTuple<out V>
{
    bool WasSuccessful { get; }
    V Value { get; }
}

public class SuccessTupleImpl<V> : ISuccessTuple<V>
{
    public bool WasSuccessful { get; }
    public V Value {get;}

    public SuccessTupleImpl(bool wasSuccessful, V value)
    {
        WasSuccessful = wasSuccessful;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public interface IInKeySemiDictionary<in K> : IDictionaryBase
{
    bool ContainsKey(K key);
    bool Remove(K key);
}

public interface IOutKeySemiDictionary<out K> : IDictionaryBase
{
    IEnumerable<K> Keys { get; }
}

public interface IOutValueSemiDictionary<out V> : IDictionaryBase
{
    IEnumerable<V> Values { get; }
}
```

Note: we don't have to cover all combinations of in/out here for the generic parameters, and also note that some of the interfaces only need a single generic parameter.The reason is some combinations of covariance/contravariance don't have any associated methods, so there's not need for corresponding types. And note that I'm leaving out the `KeyValuePair<K, V>` type- you'd need to do a similar trick on this if you wanted to include it, and it doesn't seem worth it at this stage.

So, next, the union of all those interfaces:

```
public interface IVariantDictionary<K, V> : IInKeyInValueSemiDictionary<K, V>, IInKeyOutValueSemiDictionary<K, V>,
    IOutKeySemiDictionary<K>, IDictionary<K, V>
{ }
```

And then, the wrapper class:

```
class VariantDictionaryImpl<K, V> : IVariantDictionary<K, V>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<K, V> _backingDictionary;

    public VariantDictionaryImpl(IDictionary<K, V> backingDictionary)
    {
        _backingDictionary = backingDictionary ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(backingDictionary));
    }

    public V this[K key] { set => _backingDictionary[key] = value; }

    V IInKeyOutValueSemiDictionary<K, V>.this[K key] => _backingDictionary[key];

    V IDictionary<K, V>.this[K key] { get => _backingDictionary[key]; set => _backingDictionary[key] = value; }

    public int Count => _backingDictionary.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => _backingDictionary.IsReadOnly;

    public IEnumerable<K> Keys => _backingDictionary.Keys;

    public ICollection<V> Values => _backingDictionary.Values;

    ICollection<K> IDictionary<K, V>.Keys => _backingDictionary.Keys;

    IEnumerable<V> IOutValueSemiDictionary<V>.Values => Values;

    public void Add(K key, V value)
    {
        _backingDictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<K, V> item)
    {
        _backingDictionary.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _backingDictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<K, V> item)
    {
        return _backingDictionary.Contains(item);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(K key)
    {
        return _backingDictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<K, V>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _backingDictionary.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<K, V>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _backingDictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Remove(K key)
    {
        return _backingDictionary.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<K, V> item)
    {
        return _backingDictionary.Remove(item);
    }

    public ISuccessTuple<V> TryGetValue(K key)
    {
        bool wasSuccessful = _backingDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out V v);
        return new SuccessTupleImpl<V>(wasSuccessful, v);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(K key, out V value)
    {
        return _backingDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)_backingDictionary).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Once you wrap a dictionary in this class, you can then use it either as a regular dictionary, or as any of the covariant/contravariant fragment interface types defined.

Comment: Tech heavy explanation, I like it but we need a usage example. There is a lot of work here so how does this relate back to OP's requirement and will it work and can we use it if we cannot constrain the input dictionary type.

Answer (score 2):

When I stumbled onto the same situation, I created the following helper:

```
/// <summary>
/// Casts a dictionary object to the desired Dictionary type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TKey">The target Key type.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">The target value type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="dictionary">The dictionary to cast.</param>
/// <returns>A copy of the input dictionary, casted to the provided types.</returns>
private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> CastDictionary<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary dictionary)
{
    // Get the dictionary's type.
    var dictionaryType = typeof(Dictionary<TKey, TValue>);

    // If the input is not a dictionary.
    if (dictionaryType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Dictionary<,>)))
    {
        // Throw an exception.
        throw new Exception("The cast to a dictionary failed: The input object is not a dictionary.");
    }

    // Get the generic arguments of the dictionary.
    var arguments = dictionaryType.GetGenericArguments();

    // If the first type of the dictionary is not a descendant of TKey.
    if (!(arguments[0] is TKey || arguments[0].IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TKey)))
        // Or its second type is not a descendant of TValue.
        || !(arguments[1] is TValue || arguments[1].IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TValue))))
    {
        // Throw an exception.
        throw new Exception("The cast to a dictionary failed: The input dictionary's signature does not match <" + typeof(TKey).Name + ", " + typeof(TValue).Name + ">");
    }

    // Get the dictionary's default constructor.
    var constructor = dictionaryType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);

    // Create a new dictionary.
    var output = (Dictionary<TKey, TValue>)constructor.Invoke(null);

    // Loop through the dictionary's entries.
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in dictionary)
    {
        // Insert the entries.
        output.Add((TKey)entry.Key, (TValue)entry.Value);
    }

    // Return the result.
    return output;
}
```

Could be used in your case as follows:

```
FieldInfo field = (IDictionary)this.GetType().GetField(fieldName);

Dictionary<string, Object> dict = CastDictionary<string, Object>(field.GetValue(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible to cast the `FieldInfo` to `Dictionary` as below

This is one example, I have used in my code

```
Dictionary<string, string> 
                GetTheDict = FilesAndPaths.GetType()
                             .GetFields()
                             .Where(f => f.Name.Equals(pLoadFile))
                             .Select(f => (Dictionary<string, string>)f.GetValue(FilesAndPaths))
                             .Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider whether casting to and from `object` really is necessary. I started down that path and stumbled across this article, before realising I could achieve what I needed through generics rather than conversion. For example;

```
class DictionaryUtils<T>
{
    public static T ValueOrDefault(IDictionary<string, T> dictionary, string key)
    {
        return dictionary.ContainsKey(key) ? dictionary[key] : default(T);
    }
}
```

This bit of code is much cleaner and will be faster than the equivalent conversion code shown in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation and created a WrapperDictionary class and a cast extension method. Found it helpful if you also want to make operations with it like remove a item.

Example:

```
        const string TestKey1 = "Key";
        const string TestValue1 = "Value";
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add(TestKey1, TestValue1);

        var wrapper = dict.CastDictionary<string, string, string, object>();

        wrapper.Remove(TestKey1);
```

Code:

```
public class DictionaryWrapper<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget, TKeySource, TValueSource> : IDictionary<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget>
{
    #region types

    private class EnumeratorWrapper : IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget>>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKeySource, TValueSource>> _enumerator;
        private readonly DictionaryWrapper<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget, TKeySource, TValueSource> _dictionaryWrapper;

        public EnumeratorWrapper(IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKeySource, TValueSource>> enumerator, DictionaryWrapper<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget, TKeySource, TValueSource> dictionaryWrapper)
        {
            _enumerator = enumerator;
            _dictionaryWrapper = dictionaryWrapper;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _enumerator.Dispose();
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return _enumerator.MoveNext();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _enumerator.Reset();
        }

        public KeyValuePair<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget> Current => _dictionaryWrapper._kvpSourceToTargetFunc(_enumerator.Current);

        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;
    }

    #endregion

    #region fields

    private readonly IDictionary<TKeySource, TValueSource> _dictionary;
    private readonly Func<TKeySource, TKeyTarget> _keySourceToTargetFunc;
    private readonly Func<TKeyTarget, TKeySource> _keyTargetToSourceFunc;
    private readonly Func<TValueSource, TValueTarget> _valueSourceToTargetFunc;
    private readonly Func<TValueTarget, TValueSource> _valueTargetToSourceFunc;
    private readonly Func<KeyValuePair<TKeySource, TValueSource>, KeyValuePair<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget>> _kvpSourceToTargetFunc;
    private readonly Func<KeyValuePair<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget>, KeyValuePair<TKeySource, TValueSource>> _kvpTargetToSourceFunc;

    #endregion

    #region Construction

    public DictionaryWrapper(
        IDictionary<TKeySource, TValueSource> dict, 
        Func<TKeySource, TKeyTarget> keySourceToTargetFunc = null,
        Func<TKeyTarget, TKeySource> keyTargetToSourceFunc = null, 
        Func<TValueSource, TValueTarget> valueSourceToTargetFunc = null, 
        Func<TValueTarget, TValueSource> valueTargetToSourceFunc = null)
    {
        _dictionary = dict;
        _keySourceToTargetFunc = keySourceToTargetFunc ?? (i => (TKeyTarget) (object) i);
        _keyTargetToSourceFunc = keyTargetToSourceFunc ?? (i => (TKeySource) (object) i);
        _valueSourceToTargetFunc = valueSourceToTargetFunc ?? (i => (TValueTarget) (object) i);
        _valueTargetToSourceFunc = valueTargetToSourceFunc ?? (i => (TValueSource) (object) i);
        _kvpSourceToTargetFunc = 
            kvp => new KeyValuePair<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget>(_keySourceToTargetFunc(kvp.Key), _valueSourceToTargetFunc(kvp.Value));
        _kvpTargetToSourceFunc = 
            kvp => new KeyValuePair<TKeySource, TValueSource>(_keyTargetToSourceFunc(kvp.Key), _valueTargetToSourceFunc(kvp.Value));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Interface Members

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new EnumeratorWrapper(_dictionary.GetEnumerator(), this);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget> item)
    {
        _dictionary.Add(_kvpTargetToSourceFunc(item));
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _dictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget> item)
    {
        return _dictionary.Contains(_kvpTargetToSourceFunc(item));
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKeyTarget, TValueTarget> item)
    {
        return _dictionary.Remove(_kvpTargetToSourceFunc(item));
    }

    public int Count => _dictionary.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => _dictionary.IsReadOnly;
    public bool ContainsKey(TKeyTarget key)
    {
        return _dictionary.ContainsKey(_keyTargetToSourceFunc(key));
    }

    public void Add(TKeyTarget key, TValueTarget value)
    {
        _dictionary.Add(_keyTargetToSourceFunc(key), _valueTargetToSourceFunc(value));
    }

    public bool Remove(TKeyTarget key)
    {
        return _dictionary.Remove(_keyTargetToSourceFunc(key));
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKeyTarget key, out TValueTarget value)
    {
        var success = _dictionary.TryGetValue(_keyTargetToSourceFunc(key), out TValueSource result);
        value = success ? _valueSourceToTargetFunc(result) : default;
        return success;
    }

    public TValueTarget this[TKeyTarget key]
    {
        get => _valueSourceToTargetFunc(_dictionary[_keyTargetToSourceFunc(key)]);
        set => _dictionary[_keyTargetToSourceFunc(key)] = _valueTargetToSourceFunc(value);
    }

    public ICollection<TKeyTarget> Keys => _dictionary.Keys.Select(k => _keySourceToTargetFunc(k)).ToList();
    public ICollection<TValueTarget> Values => _dictionary.Values.Select(v => _valueSourceToTargetFunc(v)).ToList();

    #endregion
}

public static class DictionaryWrapperExtensions
{
    public static IDictionary<TKeyCasted, TValueCasted> CastDictionary<TKey, TValue, TKeyCasted, TValueCasted>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        return new DictionaryWrapper<TKeyCasted,TValueCasted,TKey,TValue>(dictionary);
    }
}
```