# How can I cast an object to a dictionary of unknown type

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting

This may not be doable. I'm using reflection to iterate over an object's properties. One of those object's properties could be a Dictionary of which I do not know in advance either T type.

```
Dictionary<T, T2>
```

I need to be able to cast this to something I can iterate over to get all the values. Something like this, but this doesn't work.

```
var listTypeItems = (IDictionary>)containingObject;
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? This should actually work, see following related question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206557/c-sharp-cast-dictionarystring-anytype-to-dictionarystring-object-involvin

Comment: Doh! I didn't see the > inside the parenthesis. It was showing up as a compile error. I am so ready for this week to be over. :)

Comment: Well, at least you got there! :-)

Comment: Given the answer, this can probably be closed under: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a syntax error in my code. > inside the parenthesis shown above. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` implements `IDictionary`, which allows you to get the values in a non-statically typed way.

Comment: Hmm, I do not see how this helps him, luckily he found a typo now in the code, otherwise this would not have helped him. His original code was not any different from your suggested solution!

Comment: @PeterBranforn He was trying to cast to the generic interface, rather than the non-generic interface, which isn't going to compile.  Suggesting that he use the non-generic interface is going to make the code compile.

Comment: If you refer to the ">" this was just his typo...

Answer (score 0):

Try cast to `IDictionary`.
You can iterate on it and get `DictionaryEntry` that contains both `Key` and `Value`.