# select values from collection with generic types at runtime

Tags: c#

I have a collection of pools

```
private Dictionary<Type, object> componentPools = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
```

Each pool can be identified by its type. The `object` is always `Dictionary<Guid, TComponent>()` where `TComponent` as a generic type implements the interface `IComponent` and the Guid represents a unique ID as the key.

Just for information, a basic addition to these pools would be

```
public void AddComponentPool<TComponent>() where TComponent : IComponent
{
    componentPools.Add(typeof(TComponent), new Dictionary<Guid, TComponent>());
}
```

I would like to return an array of `Type` filled with types which are connected to a `Guid`. At first I tried to use the long and ugly run

```
List<Type> componentTypesList = new List<Type>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, object> componentPool in componentPools)
{
    Dictionary<Guid, object> pool = (Dictionary<Guid, object>)componentPool.Value;

    if (pool.Keys.Contains(entityId))
    {
        componentTypesList.Add(componentPool.Key);
    }
}

Type[] componentTypes = componentTypesList.ToArray();
```

but this code doesn't work anyway.

`Dictionary<Guid, object> pool = (Dictionary<Guid, object>)componentPool.Value;` crashes because the `Value` should be `TComponent` instead of `object`.

I also tried to use Linq, but this was even worse and doesn't work either.

```
            Type[] componentTypes = componentPools
                .Select(pool => pool.Key)
                .Where(pool => (Dictionary<Guid, object>)pool.Keys.Contains(entityId))
                .ToArray();
```

What needs to get fixed?

---

**Update:**

To make some things clear, `TComponent` is a generic and is not available in that method I want to use. My *PseudoCode* approach would be

```
    public Type[] GetTypesById(Guid entityId)
    {
        List<Type> componentTypes = new List<Type>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, object> componentPool in componentPools)
        {
            Dictionary<Guid, object> pool = (Dictionary<Guid, object>)componentPool.Value;

            if (pool.Keys.Contains(entityId))
            {
                componentTypes.Add(componentPool.Key);
            }
        }

        return componentTypes.ToArray();
    }
```

---

As @Adam requested, the full code

https://pastebin.com/b400Egzp

The relevant part is the method `AddComponentToEntity`. Please keep in mind I'm not an experienced programmer :)

Comment: Why are you using `object` when you could declare your `componentPools` variable as a `Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Guid, TComponent>>`?

Comment: You can't cast `Dictionary<Guid, TComponent>` to `Dictionary<Guid, object>` because there's no implicit conversion between those constructed dictionary types. If you have your `componentPools` declared as `Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Guid, TComponent>>` however, then `componentPool.Value` will be of type `Dictionary<Guid, TComponent>` and you can iterate over that and manually cast each value to `object`. But TBH, you haven't really given us enough info to understand what you're trying to do - maybe consider asking another question with the problem you're trying to solve and your code?

Comment: @Adam because `TComponent` is a generic

Comment: @Question3r, fair enough. The point is you need to expose your types as best you can.

Comment: I updated my question I hope this helps

Comment: foreach (var componentPool in componentPools)
   {
    var pool = componentPool.Value;
    var keys = pool.GetType().GetProperty("Keys").GetValue(pool) as List<Guid>;
    if (keys.Contains(entityId))
    {
     componentTypesList.Add(componentPool.Key);
    }
    }

Comment: @NaDeRStar I get this error `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'KeyCollection[System.Guid,ECS.Position]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]'.'`

Comment: @Question3r could you post the whole class so we can see the different scopes where types are available and required.

Comment: -Do your TComponents implement any kind of common interface?- DOH, you could use your common interface instead of object and TComponent.

Comment: @Adam you can see the full class now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10206944/2554810), you could try casting to `IDictionary` first and work off of that:

```
public Type[] GetTypesById(Guid entityId)
{
    return componentPools
              .Where(x => ((IDictionary)x.Value)
                  .Contains(entityId))
              .Select(x => x.Key)
              .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thats awesome answer

Comment: thanks for your help. Why does it work for you and not for me? I get this error `CS0119 'Queryable.Cast<TResult>(IQueryable)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context`

Comment: @Question3r I never tested it, but looking at it the dynamic cast isn't necessary since you don't actually need a full cast of the dictionary, just access to its values, see update.  Also, that's because I forgot to add `()`