# Deserialising a dictionary of dictionaries into a Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, json.net

I have serialized a dictionary named `state1` to json in C# with this code:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state1, Formatting.Indented);
```

The value of this dictionary is another dictionary and when I deserialize the json file back to dictionary the values are not deserialised as dictionaries (I cannot cast the `object` back to a `Dictionary<string, object>`):

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

How can I deserialize the json correctly?

Comment: If you want the original shape back, you need to use the original type when deserialising. What _is_ the type of `state1`? If it's a dictionary of dictionaries of string, for example, you'd need to use this when deserialising: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);`.

Comment: You have to post your json if you need some help

Comment: As it is, it's hard to understand your question.  What do you mean by ***primary shape***?  Might you please [edit] your question to explain?  Do you mean that your original dictionary was of type `Dictionary<string, T>` for some `T`, and when you deserialized it, it became a dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, object>` as specified in your call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);`?

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer.I got it .Its<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> . but is there any way to turn final shape of deserialized file to Dictionary<string, object> as a var ? cause other functions recognise this shape and you can get object as another Dictionary.

Comment: Are you saying that you are having trouble because you can't cast the objects to dictionaries due to them being instances of `JObject`?

Comment: Actually my dictionary is like <Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> and when i deserialize the json file other functions dont get it . cause they use the object as another dictionary and need this : Dictionary<string, object> .   is there any other way to turn the dictionary to string and turn back to dictionary without problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# cast Dictionary<string, AnyType> to Dictionary<string, Object> (Involving Reflection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206557/c-sharp-cast-dictionarystring-anytype-to-dictionarystring-object-involvin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the original shape back, you need to use the original type when deserialising.

If, as it seems from your comment, that it's a dictionary of dictionaries of `object`, you'd need to use this when deserialising:

```cs
var values = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>(json);
```

If you need to treat this as a `Dictionary<string, object>` while still ensuring that the inner dictionary contents are deserialised as dictionaries (and not `JObject`), you can "cast" it in this way (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10206613/622391)):

```cs
var values = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>(json)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => (object)x.Value);
```

Comment: Hi,How U doin? my other problem with json is apparently because i have  override string ToString()  in my struct files and when im trying to serialize that dictionary  (<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>)   to json file , that ovveride is not effective and when deseriazing the file and give back values to struct the errors occurs. is there any solution?

Comment: Hi @hesamgol, it's hard to say without seeing your code, but you may need to use a custom Jsonconverter, if you're using Newtonsoft: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeClass.htm. You should probably ask a new question on Stackoverflow showing your code.

Comment: Tnx for answering my question. I think your right but i dont know how to use it . ill make new question. tnx bro